# Spring-servlet.xml parsing with Hibernate and Liquibase

Tags: java, xml, spring, eclipse, maven

After many tries and days working i don't know where is the wrong part. I give my code in order to ask for some help.

I update clean using maven with this pom:

pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/5.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/5.0.0 
                            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-5.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.karma</groupId>
  <artifactId>gema</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <finalName>gema</finalName>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Plugin de LiquiBase -->
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>classpath:database/db-changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase</url>
                    <username>hxplus</username>
                    <password>hxplus</password>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>update</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.0</version>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


  <name>Gema Maven Webapp</name>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <name>OSS Sonatype Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

But when trying to run in tomcat8.5 using this servlet:

servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.karma.gema.model" />


        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gema" />
        <property name="username" value="karma" />
        <property name="password" value="karma" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:database/db-changelog.xml" />

        <!-- contexts specifies the runtime contexts to use. -->
        <property name="contexts" value="test, production" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.karma.gema" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.karma.gema.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"/>


</beans>
```

I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/lib/gema-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
```

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen, Spring 5.0.0, Maven, Tomcat 8.5, Hibernate in Debian Stretch.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exception seems to be a library incompatibility issue. You are using Spring 5.0.0, but at the same time you have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

From Spring Data JPA [change log](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/changelog.txt) it seems that Spring 5 support was added only in `v1.10.6.RELEASE`

Try updating Spring Data JPA version. I have verified that `v2.0.0.RELEASE` is compiled with Spring 5 as a dependency.

Comment: I've do as you said but now i have problems using the @Query annotation. Have any clues where to search usage in this version?

Comment: All was resolved updating all the references. Thank you.